# setInterval only executes once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React component where on form submit, a timer takes in the value input from a slider component and starts to count down to zero. However, it is only the timer stops after 1 of the setInterval function in triggerClock(). I'm not sure what to do.

My React component:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  let timeInMinutes;
  let timeInSeconds;

  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  const handleTimeChange = (event) => {
    setTime(event.target.value);
  };

  const triggerClock = () => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

      if (seconds === 0) {
        setSeconds((sec) => sec + 59);
        setMinutes((min) => min - 1);
      } else {
        setSeconds((sec) => sec - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    timeInMinutes = time;
    timeInSeconds = timeInMinutes * 60;
    setMinutes(timeInSeconds / 60);
    setSeconds(timeInSeconds % 60);
    triggerClock();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Container maxWidth="xs" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Typography variant="h5">Set Time (Minutes)</Typography>
        <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
          <Slider
            aria-label="Timer"
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            step={10}
            marks
            min={0}
            max={60}
            value={time}
            onChange={handleTimeChange}
          />
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Box>
        <div>
          {minutes}:{seconds}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here; first I'd suggest you have a read of Dan Abramov's excellent [Making setInterval declarative](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) blog post which is a great way to get your head around the tricky intersection of `setInterval` and React Hooks.

Firstly, you're putting too much stuff into React state. Your `minutes` and `seconds` can be directly, and trivially, derived from `time`. We don't need React to look after them for us, they are relevant only during "this render". so:

```
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  const seconds = time % 60;
```

Secondly, in the spirit of Dan's quote:

> "we can describe the process at all points in time simultaneously"

we need to know, and control, whether the timer is counting down or not:

```
const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false);

...

const triggerClock = () => {
  setTimerRunning(true);
};
```

Note that an additional benefit of this is we can now make our GUI reflect the state:

```
<Button disabled={timerRunning} type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

And finally, we have all the necessary parts to write a `useEffect` that will encompass the `setInterval` with the desired countdown, stop at the right time *and* clean up the interval:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timerRunning) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((oldTime) => {
          const newTime = oldTime - 1;
          if (newTime === 0) {
            setTimerRunning(false);
          }
          return newTime;
        });
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }
  }, [timerRunning]);
```